# How to use Stewart theorem to prove this result?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

> If a line is perpendicular to two distinct lines in a plane, then it is perpendicular to any line in this plane.

Is there any way to prove this result from [Stewart Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20geometry%2C%20Stewart%27s%20theorem%20yields,published%20the%20theorem%20in%201746)? I started out of contradiction, but then I didn't understand where to start applying Stewart's theorem. By the way, I don't see a relationship with Stewart's theorem either.

[image]

Could anyone give a hint to this problem?

Comment: I don't see how we can apply Stewart theorem. The lines can be skewed with no possibility even to form a triangle.

Comment: I added an image so that we can better understand what needs proved, basically we want $\alpha=90$. But how, from Stewart's theorem, to get there is a mystery. My teacher didn't even pass Stewart's theorem in class.

Comment: For Stewart theorem we need a triangle with a cevian. Which triangle do you have in mind? All three triangles in the picture are in different planes, that's why I think that we cannot apply the theorem to prove the statement

Comment: It's possible to use Stewart's theorem. Not sure it's an improvement over [the standard proof](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookXI/propXI4.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose points $B$ and $C$ on lines $s$ and $s'$ such that segment $BC$ intersects line $t$ at $D$. In addition, set
$PB=b$, $PC=c$, $CD=n$, $BD=m$, $PD=d$, $AD=d'$, $AP=h$.

From Stewart's theorem applied to triangle $PBC$ one gets:
$$
b^2m+c^2n=(m+n)(d^2+mn).
$$
From Stewart's theorem applied to triangle $ABC$, taking into account that $AB=\sqrt{b^2+h^2}$, $AC=\sqrt{c^2+h^2}$, one gets:
$$
(b^2+h^2)m+(c^2+h^2)n=(m+n)(d'^2+mn).
$$
Subtracting the previous equality we thus get:
$$
h^2=d'^2-d^2
$$
which entails $\angle APD=90°$.

[image]

Comment: very clever, thanks!